# Generate metadata.json from metadata.rb without Chef or knife

Tags: ruby, json, metadata, chef-infra

I'm working on a program that will interact with Chef. I would like to read metadata looking for dependencies and maybe other information like name, but Chef is not suposed to be installed on the machine running it. I think the best way is translate metadata.rb to metadata.json and read it.

Actually, I'm reading line by line each recipe with an algorithm based [on this](https://gist.github.com/364326) but I think is more correct use metadata like Chef do. Moreover, it has problems with expressions like this:

```
node['apache']['default_modules'].each do |mod|
  recipe_name = mod =~ /^mod_/ ? mod : "mod_#{mod}"
  include_recipe "apache2::#{recipe_name}"
end
```

Same problem reading role's run_list when it has more than one line. Definitely, it could be so much better if I could translate it to json file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

It uses ruby `instance_eval` method to parse the `metadata.rb` from cookbook, So the key is the spec of `metadata.rb`. which is defined in [`Chef::Cookbook::Metadata`](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/cookbook/metadata.rb).

It's ruby class that provides a number of methods. so you can tailer your own program to use minimum set of methods besides attribute accessor like `name`, `maintainer` like `depends()` and `recipe(name, description)`.

Answer (score 0):

With only the Chef client installed, this script will do the trick. Place it in the same folder as the expanded cookbook.

```
require 'chef/cookbook/metadata'
require 'json'

contents = File.read('metadata.rb')
c = Chef::Cookbook::Metadata.new
c.instance_eval(contents)
File.write('metadata.json', c.to_json)
```

Or I imagine you can install only the Chef gems over your Ruby installation (this is my second Ruby program, so you'll know better how this is done)